# How to add multiple variable array to database

Tags: php, mysql, implode

i want to insert my data to database, i have two variable that have array datas.

for example `$_POST['link']`<= Array data, `$_POST['nama_link']`<= Array data and `$id_baru`<= not Array.

here what i can do

```
$prep = array();
    foreach($_POST['link'] as $v ) {
        $prep[] = "($id_baru, $v)";
    }

    $add_link = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO link_relation (`id_e_lr`,`link_lr`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $prep));
    $add_link = $add_link->execute($prep);
```

code above only add `$_POST['link']` and `$id_baru` what i have to do to insert `$_POST['nama_link']` on it.

my table

```
id_e_lr   link_lr           nama_link_lr
========  =========        ==============
$id_baru  `$_POST['link']  $_POST['nama_link']
$id_baru  `$_POST['link']  $_POST['nama_link']
$id_baru  `$_POST['link']  $_POST['nama_link']
$id_baru  `$_POST['link']  $_POST['nama_link']
```

Comment: what column you have in table for `nama_link`?

Comment: _sidenote:_ the insert statements needs `()` around the values. Also you don't really prepare when you paste the values already in the sql string.

Comment: @Jeff  that is in case of single values need to be inserted. She already have `()`, if you will see again

Comment: @AlivetoDie im edit my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keys of first array iteration to get values from `$_POST['nama_link']` and add it to insert values too.

Also try to use `prepared statement` concept properly.

Do like below:-

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO link_relation (`id_e_lr`,`link_lr`,`nama_link_lr`) VALUES (:id_baru, :v, :link)");

foreach ($_POST['link'] as $key=>$v){
    if(isset($_POST['nama_link'][$key])){
        $link = $_POST['nama_link'][$key];
    }
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':id_baru' => $id_baru,
        ':v' => $v,
        ':link' => $link,
    ));
}
```

Comment: @Jazuly  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

If you use prepared statement, you can't directly bind arrays to db columns.

You have to do this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $var1, $var2, $var3);
foreach ($_POST['link'] as $i) {
    $var1 = $i['key1'];
    $var2 = $i['key2'];
    $var3 = $i['key3'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Where keyN is your index inside $_POST.